# Is it impossible to finish the last quest in Ashen?

Tags: ashen

I just finished the last quest, got the credits, quit out of them by holding B, and quit the game. Then I thought maybe there would be some interesting changes to the world, so I loaded it back up and clicked "Continue" on the main screen. Now I'm back in Vagrant's Rest, but the only thing that's changed is my scoria count. No spoilers, but I had expected at least the main quest to be marked as finished, but the quest and marker were still there. Is this normal?

Comment: Did the game create a post-campaign savegame? It's not uncommon for games to be reset to before the point of no return in the final mission, when reloading them after finishing the game.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Official answer from [their Discord](https://discordapp.com/channels/491366369443446784/545795935855312927):

> It's to allow players to go back and explore if they want of complete any quests they might not have finished yet